# Odata service with ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-addin, project-server, adfs

Adding Sharepoint Odata service Web reference, keeps respond with 403 forbidden error, or bad request. This issue mainly cause of using ADFS as authentication provider.

the environment is : Sharepoint 2013, with Project server application service installed, and it is the data source of our data report, the application I try to run is a console application within the same farm of the sharepiont.

Comment: Are you getting the token, then using the token to create the cookie, and then storing the cookie?